# custom useFetch composable doesn't work as expected

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, composable, usefetch

I'm trying to create a composable function in my nuxt 3 project to fetch some date from my strapi cms.
I want to simplify the fetch function in all components and pages i have to a simple method with 2 or 3 parameters, like path or an optional pick argument. the composable function should then execute the useFetch with the baseURL and the strapi apiToken from the runtimeConfig and also a transform function after getting back the response.

This is a working code snipped from a vue page to test:

```js
<template>
    <div id="dev">
        <h1>Dev</h1>
        <h3>Test Fetches</h3>
        <p v-if="pending">Pending</p>
        <p v-else-if="data">Data: {{ data }}</p>
        <p v-else-if="error">Error: {{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const headers = new Headers();
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    if (process.server) console.log(runtimeConfig);
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer: ${runtimeConfig.apiToken}`)
    const { data: data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('/api/[content-type]?populate=deep', {
        baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseUrl,
        headers,
        transform: (response) => {
            return response.data;
        },
        // pick: ['id']
    })
    if (process.server) console.log(data);
</script>
```

I tried to move this to a composable fetchStrapi.js:

```js
export const fetchStrapi = async (path, pick = []) => {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    if (process.server) console.log(runtimeConfig);
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer: ${runtimeConfig.apiToken}`)
    const { data: data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(path, {
        baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseUrl,
        headers,
        transform: (response) => {
            return response.data;
        },
        pick
    })
    if (process.server) console.log(data);
    return { data: data, pending, error, refresh }
}
```

and run it from the dev page:

```js
<template>
    <div id="dev">
        <h1>Dev</h1>
        <h3>Test Fetches</h3>
        <p v-if="pending">Pending</p>
        <p v-else-if="data">Data: {{ data }}</p>
        <p v-else-if="error">Error: {{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const { data: data, pending, error, refresh } = fetchStrapi('/api/[content-type]?populate=deep');
    if (process.server) console.log(data);
</script>
```

but the content in data is not displayed and the console of the server tells:

```bash
undefined
RefImpl {
  __v_isShallow: false,
  dep: undefined,
  __v_isRef: true,
  _rawValue: {},
  _value: {}
}
```

I already added a await before the fetchStrapi function which results in `Data:` being displayed in the browser, but still not the answer i am expecting

My nuxt.config.ts looks like this:

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  runtimeConfig: {
    apiToken: '',
    public: {
      apiBaseUrl: 'https://[urlToStrapi]',
    }
  }
})
```

API Token comes from a `.env` file.

What's wrong?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think you should put await before fetchStrapi every time you use it